# Stop and restart `flalign*` environment

Tags: flalign

I want to create an `flalign*` environment in which there are some instructions in the form of text, aligned to the left also, but not disturbing the alignment of the rest of the equation system.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{flalign*}
  this~is &= an~equation&&\\
  &= yet~another~equation&&\\
  \text{here's some text that I'd want to have aligned left, without disturbing the equation alignment system}&&\\
  &= and~the~continued~equation~system
 \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

In my above MWE, the `\text{~}` section shifts the whole system of equations to the right, although I'd like all the equations to be aligned to the left.

I'd like to be able to stop and then restart `flalign*` where it was, for two reasons:

1. The alignment of the text will be independent from that of the equations, resulting in les problems.
2. The appropriate margin will be placed between the text a equation systems, just like it would for any text that is independent of an equation system environment. What I don't like in my MWE is that the text is squished into the equation system as though it is an equation itself, although I'd like it to stand out more, and have spacing that is coherent with the rest of my document.

So, to recap, I want to start an `flalign*` environment, "pause" it, insert one or more generic lines of text in my document, then restart the `flalign*` where it was, in such a way that both equation systems be aligned to each other.

**NOTE:** If, for whatever reason, your solution results in *all* the equation systems in the document being aligned to each other, then that won't solve it for me, as I also have many `flalign*` environments that I want to keep independent from each other within my same document.

Comment: Use `\intertext` instead of `\text`.

Comment: See also `\shortintertext` (mathtools package).

Comment: @IanThompson Works! Thank you.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks! For those interested, see page 11 of the `amsmath` manual: https://www.ams.org/arc/tex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, don't use `flalign`. If you want **f**lush **l**eft equations, pass `amsmath` the relevant options. Then you can and should use `equation` for single equations, or `gather` for groups of unaligned ones.

Here I set `\mathindent` to zero, but I recommend not doing it.

What you need is `\intertext`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

I'm not sure why using \texttt{flalign}
\begin{flalign*}
  this~is &= an~equation&&\\
  &= yet~another~equation&&
  \intertext{here's some text that I'd want to have aligned left, 
    without disturbing the equation alignment system}
  &= and~the~continued~equation~system
\end{flalign*}
because \texttt{align} is much easier
\begin{align*}
  this~is &= an~equation\\
  &= yet~another~equation
  \intertext{here's some text that I'd want to have aligned left,
    without disturbing the equation alignment system}
  &= and~the~continued~equation~system
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes, you're right. I was just blindly using `flalign*` because it's the first command I fell upon on the internet, but I can see why it'd be bad practice. I appreciate you answering so clearly and completely, and solving that extra issue. Peace.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the below (not sure whether it exactly match with you)

```
 \begin{flalign*}
\intertext{this is} &= \text{an equation}\\
  &= \text{yet another equation}\\
\intertext{there's some text that I'd want to have aligned left, without disturbing the equation alignment system}
  &= \text{and the continued equation system}
 \end{flalign*}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I missed to add `\mathindent`, thanks to sir `egreg`

Comment: Thank you! Your answer works perfectly. +1. I marked **egreg**'s as the solution because it's more complete, but your answer is just fine too. I appreciate your time, and God bless you.

Comment: @GPWR Thanks for your kind words.